# Angular - push element in array makes problems with pipes

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two pipes on an array of objects :

```
export class ArrayFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(array: Array<any>, args: ArrayFilterPipeArgsInterface): any {
        if(args.searchText == null) return array;

        return array.filter(function(elem) {
            return elem[args.item].toLowerCase().indexOf(args.searchText.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        });
    }
}
```

And :

```
export class ArraySortPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(records: Array<any>, args: ArraySortPipeArgsInterface): any {
        if(!records) return [];
        if(!records.length) return records;

        const direction = args.isDesc ? -1 : 1;

        return records.sort(function(a, b) {
            if(a[args.property] < b[args.property])
                return -1 * direction;
            else if( a[args.property] > b[args.property])
                return direction;
            else
                return 0;
        });
    }
}
```

Applied like this :

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items | arrayFilter: {searchText: itemsFilter, item: 'name'} | arraySort: {property: column, isDesc: isDesc}">
    <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
</tr>
```

`itemsFilter` comes from an input, it works well as is.

But if I sort by `ID` in descending order, when I programmatically add a new element :

```
this.itemsService.create(form.value, true).subscribe(
    newItem => {
        this.items.push({
            id: newItem.resp.id,
            name: form.value.name
        });
    }
);
```

It appears at the end of the list, even though it's ID is the biggest. Also, if I filtered the array using `itemsFilter`, it will be added to the current displayed elements even if it doesn't match the search.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Please read https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe.

Comment: That's incredibly interesting, thanks ! I modified this to use them as suggested and all works well :) If you want to post this as an answer I'm sure it will be helpfull to others as well.

Comment: @JBNizet just because the framework is opinionated in such a way that it chose not to provide it doesn't mean it is not useful. Just use slice.

Comment: @AluanHaddad what do you mean by slice ?

Comment: `[].slice()` is a simple way to create a copy of an array. Filter already does this but sort doesn't so you should `return records.slice().sort(f);` which maintains the purity of the pipe and is generally good practice when sorting arrays.